# Sequelize – id as uuid – automatic creation with bulkInsert

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a model with such init:

```
Group.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
});
```

I also have an associated migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Groups', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      name: Sequelize.STRING,
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Groups');
  },
};
```

I'm trying to `bulkInsert` inside the seeders while creating groups and I'm passing only a `name` property, expecting the DB to create uuids:

```
const groups = [{ name: 'group-1' }, { name: 'group-2' }];
return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Groups', groups, {
  returning: true,
  validate: true,
  individualHooks: true,
});
},
```

Yet there is an error during this seed:

```
ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I automatically generate uuids?

Comment: I've a similar issue. Did you find a solution for yours?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue. In my case (on the migration file), I changed

```
defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
```

to

```
defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
```

PS: I was working on Postgres, so uuid modules needed to be enabled on the schema